# RxSwift obtain value from one item in Observable sequence

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to gradually convert my App to RxSwift / MVVM. But I think I'm doing some things incorrectly.

In this example I have a static table with this specific information.

```
    let itens = Observable.just([
        MenuItem(name: GlobalStrings.menuItemHome,      nameClass: "GPMainVC"),
        MenuItem(name: GlobalStrings.menuItemProfile,   nameClass: "GPMainVC"),
        MenuItem(name: GlobalStrings.menuItemLevels,    nameClass: "GPLevelsVC"),
    ])
```

I need to know the model(MenuItem) and the index when the user select a cell, but I am having trouble doing that

```
 tableView.rx
        .itemSelected
        .map { [weak self] indexPath in
            return (indexPath, self?.modelView.itens.elementAt(indexPath.row))
        }
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] indexPath, model in

            self?.tableView.reloadData()

            //can´t get MenuItem because model its a observable
            //self?.didSelect((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row, name.nameClass)

        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your `itens` really a _sequence_ (because that's what observables really are, that is sequences of events that you can "watch on")?  The way it looks, `itens` is just some sort of a dictionary that you want to use to look `MenuItem` up from. If that's the case, then you should not make an observable out of it.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Anton Bronnikov. But what you suggest to use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do next steps:

1. Use Variable. I think it's a better solution in your situation.

   ```
   let itens = Variable([
       MenuItem(name: GlobalStrings.menuItemHome, nameClass: "GPMainVC"),
       MenuItem(name: GlobalStrings.menuItemProfile, nameClass: "GPMainVC"),
       MenuItem(name: GlobalStrings.menuItemLevels, nameClass: "GPLevelsVC"),
   ])
   ```
2. Use the following code if you want to get index and model from a clicked cell.

   ```
   tableView.rx
   .itemSelected
   .map { index in
       return (index, self.items.value[index.row])
   }
   .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] index, model in
       // model is MenuItem class
   })
   .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
   ```

   I hope my answer was very helpful for you. Please let me know if you want more information about RxSwift opportunities in your task. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Svyatoslav. But i need both the index and the model. That's why i was trying to use the itemSelected operator. Any idea how to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: @DaSilva, I have just fixed my answer. Check it please.

Comment: @DaSilva, please don't forget to mark my answer as right if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. But with "let itens = Variable" i lost the option to use "tens.bindTo"

Comment: @DaSilva, you should use items.asObservable().bindTo().